# I am able to create a table in Redshift using Python but not able to do the same operation fr SQL Worlbench

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, scripting, amazon-redshift

I have one problem statement that I am able to write successfully create a table in Redshift through Python but whenever I try to do the same operation from SQL Workbench Client it's not happening and throwing me some error that I don't have access to the schema

Comment: Welcome to SO. "throwing me some error" - this will not be helpful for someone who can help you.. pls read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you I will make a note of it

Comment: @Sohail Your Python script seems to have login credentials that do allow you to access the schema. So maybe your connection in SQL Workbench is using different credentials?

Comment: @NielsJoaquin I am connecting the SQL Workbench with my same login credentials but not getting into it